# How much lower is max q if launching from high altitude (i.e. mountain top)?

Tags: falcon-9, rocket-equation, max-q, high-altitude-launch

I looked at very simple max q formula: q=1/2 ρv^2 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_q). As air density is lower with altitude, the max q should be lower as well, and also should occur at higher altitude.
using this formula, I estimated for Falcon 9 that Mount Everest should reduce max q by 16 times, compared to sea level launch and max-Q altitude increases about from 7km to 11 km.

But then I saw this post: [Is it possible to calculate Max-Q without having to input an altitude](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/30704/is-it-possible-to-calculate-max-q-without-having-to-input-an-altitude), which basically says "it's complicated".
Is it possible to significantly reduce real max q by launching of high altitude? And by how much?

[image: Max q change due to altitude]

Comment: Hmmm.. somewhere in there you have to posit an acceleration profile so you know the speed as a func of time and therefore as a func of altitude.  I"m guessing you expect the same profile, in which case graphing  $\rho*v^2$ vs. time is easy; but if you start at higher altitude, drag is less, so the accel profile for the same **thrust** profile will differ.

Comment: Hopefully someone with a simulation will run this. Interesting.