# Understanding Coefficient of Drag Verses Mach Number for Launch Vehicles

Tags: mission-design, aerodynamics, amateur-rocketry

I've been working on a design for a sounding rocket that can go to the Karman line, that I want to make my senior capstone project next year.  As a part of this process, I am making a program to estimate the maximum altitude attained by the rocket and its going pretty well.

Here is the estimated flight for a 1000lbf engine with 120 lbs of total rocket and 80% fuel by weight:
[image]

However, the current estimation I have is still a huuuuuge over estimation because it does not consider the effects of trans and supersonic flight on the coefficient of drag, which I imagine will have a dramatic impact on this code's output (notice the max velocity is 6800 ft/s...)

I was able to find this image relating atlas Cd to mach number here:

[image]

See [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/12650/12102) and [way back machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20170313142729/http://www.braeunig.us/apollo/saturnV.htm) for source.

How can I make a curve similar to this for our project?  The rocket body is going to be a (ogive or parabolic probably) cone with a long cylindrical body and fins.  I estimate that the Cd will be about .2-.25 at low speed flight.

How can I go about making a curve like this?  How do I know at what mach number the pressure will be highest for my design?  Should I change nose-cone shape to reduce drag at sonic speed?  Are there any resources to guide me in the right direction here?  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  We have access to a pretty slow wind tunnel and fluid dynamics software if that can help us any.

Thanks!

Comment: How fast is a "pretty slow" wind tunnel?

Comment: @RussellBorogove I've added a link to one of your answers (as source for the figure).

Comment: Welcome to *Space*, and congratulations on writing our 9000th question!

Comment: @Russel Borogrove  Its only 90 MPH.  I might also be able to ask some nearby aerospace companies if they have a tunnel.  I might have some connections that can help me out, but if I start asking I need a plan on how to collect the data I need.

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer, but [this paper](http://www.dept.aoe.vt.edu/~mason/Mason_f/ConfigAeroSupersonicNotes.pdf) on supersonic aerodynamics might be helpful. I note that figure 10-9 shows many aircraft having a generally similar Cd vs mach curve up to M2.0 that is not too dissimilar from the Atlas data. While you're waiting for a better answer you could do worse than estimating a curve based on those models and your low-speed data...

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you can find data from a similar flight at the CSXT web site:  http://www.ddeville.com/GoFast_Flight_data.xls   That the velocity curve doesn't have the sharp cusp that yours does, which makes me wonder where that comes from.  (The main CSXT page describes the rocket: http://www.ddeville.com/derek/CSXT.htm)

Comment: @BobJacobsen Good observation.  In this flight model, I do not take into account the change of thrust as a function of the altitude due to expansion ratio, and I do not have a thrust curve which decreases thrust as a function of the tank pressure (this is a work in progress).  As a result the thrust is constant as the density of air drops, so the velocity is concave up as expected.  Thanks for that excel table, I think this will be very useful to verify our code!