# Drag and lift coefficient tables/plots for Saturn V/Space Shuttle/Other

Tags: space-shuttle, saturn-v, simulation, lift, drag

I'm looking for drag and lift coefficient data to plug into my launch simulation.

I could assume constant coefficients, but I'd like to structure my model to accept lookup tables, so I'm looking for representative data that I can use to test my model.

This would ideally be plots or tables for rockets "in the public domain". Saturn V maybe, or the space shuttle, or any other rocket for which this data might be available (preferably one comparable in size to Falcon 9).

Huge thanks if you can share where to find this!

Comment: There is some information for Saturn V in [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32265/12102) which links to https://web.archive.org/web/20170313142729/http://www.braeunig.us/apollo/saturnV.htm some of which I used in [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/30705/12102).

Comment: Thank you! That's a great starting point :)

Comment: I found the document I was remembering but sadly it's Orbiter-only https://archive.org/details/nasa_techdoc_19810067693 Have not seen the Launch Vehicle Aerodynamic Data volume online.